# web developer 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-web-developer

Hey....where is the "web service" type of project? i see "web site" but not "web service".

Any idea?

TY

Comment: Downvote with no comment is unreasonable. The question seems fine to me.

Comment: Are asking about VS 2010? I think you might be looking for WCF project.

Comment: @spender Why didn't you upvote it then?

Comment: It's an OK question, not a good question. Given the weight of an upvote versus a downvote, I don't think it's a fair way to redress other people's downvotes.

Comment: Jason, are you saying this is the only way to create a web service from now?

Comment: I find this question unclear because of lack of context.

Answer (score 3):

WCF Project for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ([source here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/netfxsetup/thread/56191c85-c29e-4b4c-805a-b3cc2ab45647))

[image]

WCF Project for Microsoft Visual Developer 2010 ([source here](http://jalpesh.blogspot.com/2009/10/review-of-microsoft-visual-web.html))
[image]

Comment: by me i don't get this option in 2010.

Comment: If not, please post the exact name of the IDE you are using. (Example : Microsoft Visual Studio 2008)

Comment: Hey. thank you very much. I see it now. So i need to create a "asp.net web application"??

Comment: @user181421 No. Do `WCF Service Application`.

Comment: Then what? do you have a link for a step by step tutorial on this?

Comment: I think you should post another question (or google) about **exactly** what you are trying to make.